# Can I sell a .eu domain to a registrant outside the European Union?

Tags: domains, godaddy, ebay, tld-restrictions

I would like to sell my domain, which is a [.eu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.eu) domain.

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.eu) states that .eu domains may only be registered by residents of member states of the European Union.

For that reason, I wonder if it would make sense to offer my domain for sale at websites directed at the US markets (sedo.com, ebay.com, etc), since the buyer would, at least technically speaking, not register the domain, only 'acquire' (read: buy secondhand) it.

Comment: @johnconde Can you please look at [my meta question](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/650/is-this-really-an-off-topic-question)?

Comment: @PeeHaa: I will

Comment: Why is this question tagged with "godaddy"? The domain in question is not registered at godaddy, and IRCC, godaddy doesn't offer .eu domains for registration.

Comment: Looks like an invalid edit to me. You can always rollback the changes if you think it was. I don't like the title change myself.

Comment: @PeeHaa: After visiting godaddy, it turned out they *do* sell .eu domains. But still, odd.

Comment: @hiobs they run a domain auction site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key point is that once you've sold the domain, you would need to transfer "the ownership" or more accurately "the registration" to the new owner, who would need to be an EU resident or organisation.

When you take ownership of a domain name, regardless of who you bought it from, you then need to register the ownership with ICANN or an accredited registrar (in this case EURid).

See the "[Transfer your domain name](https://eurid.eu/en/my-eu/)" page - as this trade will need to be mediated by an accredited .eu registrar, you'll need to find one who is willing to neglect to check that the new registrant is an EU organisation/resident (presumably opening themselves up to losing their accreditation).

Answer (score 1):

You could use any of those sites, so long as you make clear in the advert that the purchaser has to be an EU resident then you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that .eu domain names are restricted to European citizens and European companies, there's nothing stopping the person you sell to from using a 'Trustee Service'.

The Trustee Service is used by people who wish to purchase certain ccTLDs which have restrictions such as a business, address, or SSN within the country. There are a lot of registrars that use their local contacts to provide the necessary documentation towards the purchase of said domain.

You can try and see if the registrar would be willing to act as a sort of intermediary between you and the purchaser of your domain.